# Java monitoring class

Tags: java

I'm working on a project in which I have the source code of of an **arbitrary** java program. I will then compile and then initiate said class (Not the problem). But I need a 'supervisor' class that tracks disk i/o of that program or any of its objects. Parsing the source code and counting calls to know classes that perform Disk I/O is not going to work. I'm going to use how much the disk reads and writes as part of a program analysis.
So an example would look like this:

```
    customClass c;
    Supervisor sup = new Supervisor(c);
    c.create();//calls constructor
    /* 
        Various test and functions calls to customClass
    */
sup.WriteBytes();//Total bytes written by customClass at this point
sup.ReadBytes();//Total bytes read by customClass at this point
sup.WriteTimes();//Total times customClass wrote to disk at this point
sup.readTimes();//Total times customClass read from disk at this point
```

Is this possible and if so could someone provide an example?

Comment: You can count how often code requested read/write/delete access to a file by implementing a custom [`SecurityManager`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/SecurityManager.html) that logs this information in its `checkRead()`/`checkWrite()`/`checkDelete()` methods. No idea about the counting of bytes, though.

Comment: Maybe look at using a tool like `strace` instead of a Java class?